# How I can resolve this Procedure in Oracle PLSQL (It's not homework or something like that)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

I'm learning Oracle Database and PL/SQL. I'm trying to create a PROCEDURE to query annual salary for an specific employee. What is wrong with my code? Thanks.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE annual_salary (
  p_lname IN employees23.last_name%TYPE,
  p_empid IN employees23.employee_id%TYPE)
IS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    v_annualsal employees23.salary%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT salary*12
    INTO v_annualsal
    FROM employees23
    WHERE last_name = p_lname;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_annualsal);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No existe empleado');
  END;
END annual_salary;
/
BEGIN
  annual_salary('Russell');
END;
```

Comment: What is the problem? are you having an error, an unexpected behaviour?It seems thet you are declaring a procedure with 2 parameters, but you call it with only one

Comment: Yes! Informe de error -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ANNUAL_SALARY'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Well, you've defined the procedure with two arguments, then called it with only one...

Comment: WOW I didn't know it!! So... If I define two parameters into procedure I have to call both parameters in the executable section? Thanks for your help. I'm very very noob.

Comment: Sure looks like homework to me.  In any event, your EXCEPTION handler is fatally flawed. dbms_ouput only writes to a buffer.  It is up to the client program on whether or not to write the contents of that buffer to a screen, printer, cocktail napkin, whatever.  And even then, will not write until the procedure completes.

Comment: You can declare variables above the first `begin` (the whole `create or replace` clause takes the place of a `declare`), so you don't need the second level of nesting. And as @EdStevens mentioned, `dbms_output` is for basic debugging, not production error handling.

Comment: Thanks! I'm learning PLSQL, I'm very noob!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table employees23 as 
    select 10 emp_id, cast('Russell' as varchar2(30)) last_name, 6000.00 salary
    from dual; 

create or replace procedure annual_salary (lname employees23.last_name%type) is
    annualsal employees23.salary%type;
begin
    select salary*12 into annualsal
    from employees23
    where last_name = lname
    ;
    dbms_output.put_line (lname || ' has ' || annualsal || ' p.a.');
exception when no_data_found then
    raise_application_error (-20000, 'emploee ' || lname || ' does not exists');
end annual_salary;
/

exec  annual_salary('Russell');
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your help!